# INSERT INTO called once but runs twice (not in a loop)

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

I have a query which each time it is encountered, is run twice, which is not intended.  I have added logging to a file before and after it and clear the file before running the script.

I don't think I need to post the other code because I believe that my logging proves that this query is called only once.

The code:

```
file_put_contents(
    $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/PDOErrors.txt',
    "\n\nImmediately before ban query 1. ".date('r ')." (1)",
    FILE_APPEND);

$sth=$Mdbh->query("
    INSERT INTO
        banned_IP
    SET
        ip_add      = '$ip',
        proxy_ip    = '$proxy_ip'
");
$sth->execute();

file_put_contents(
    $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/PDOErrors.txt',
    "\n\nBanned the user using query1. ".date('r ')." (2)",
    FILE_APPEND);

return 999;
```

Note that there is a `return` immediately after it is run too and even if it was called twice, my `PDOErrors.txt` file would show the diagnostic data for each run, which it doesn't.

The first diagnostic data into `PDOErrors.txt` runs but the second doesn't run ever!

Here is a copy of the PDOErrors.txt

```
Immediately before ban query 1. Thu, 21 Mar 2013 13:38:56 +0800  (1)

exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '127.0.0.1' for key 'ip_add'' in /home/peter/Documents/websites/Our_websites/bookkeeper/books.bookkeeper/public/includes/classes/loginAttempt.class.php:137
Stack trace:
#0 /home/peter/Documents/websites/Our_websites/bookkeeper/books.bookkeeper.ph/public/includes/classes/loginAttempt.class.php(137): PDOStatement->execute()
#1 /home/peter/Documents/websites/Our_websites/bookkeeper/books.bookkeeper.ph/public/includes/classes/login.class.php(980): loginAttempt->recordLoginAttempt(Array)
#2 /home/peter/Documents/websites/Our_websites/bookkeeper/books.bookkeeper.ph/public/ajax/login.user.php(25): Login->doLogin(Array)
#3 {main}
```

I should mention that I completely empty the `banned_IP` database table before each run.

I'm also logging all queries as this is a development environment and the log of the query can be seen below:

```
708 Query     INSERT INTO
                        banned_IP
              SET
                        ip_add          = '127.0.0.1',
                        proxy_ip        = ''

708 Query     INSERT INTO
                        banned_IP
              SET
                        ip_add          = '127.0.0.1',
                        proxy_ip        = ''
708 Quit
```

I think I'm satisfied that the query is only being called once as the PDOErrors.txt would include two sets of diagnostic data if not. The error message appears to be generated on the very first run of the query on an empty database table. What could be causing this please?

Comment: I had something like this problem once, there was a script on my page which it was loading slider images based on the visible one, there was a new request for each of the images and because of my URL rewriting, everything was pointing to my `index.php` first and then get loaded. I hope this tip might help you as I'm not sure what's your system malfunction exactly.

Comment: Thanks @MahanGM, I'm not sure if that applies in my case according to Firebug, only one http request is being sent, but thanks for your input.

Comment: I've found a workaround. The database table had `ip_add` indexed as unique, but when I added an `id` column with an auto-increment value, suddenly it no longer errors, although it does enter it twice still. Must be a bug in MySQL I think, since if the script was run more than once, PDOErrors.txt would show it. I think this work-around will suffice for me, since this is a rarely run process.

Comment: Why in the world are you using `SET` with an insert command? `INSERT INTO table (column, names) VALUES ('column', 'values')` or to do an update: `UPDATE table SET column = 'column', names = 'values' WHERE something = 'this'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PDO->query will execute a query and return PDOStatement object, now you are again executing the returned PDOStatement which cause this error.

Use PDO->prepare which returns PDOStatement object and then execute the statement OR just use PDO->query and DO NOT execute the PDOStatement